# How to get tensor value in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I try to create custom layer in Keras. This code I get from examples. How to get result of calculation this Layer?

```
  class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
        def __init__(self, units=32):
            super(Linear, self).__init__()
            self.units = units

        def build(self, input_shape):
            self.w = self.add_weight(
                shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                initializer="random_normal",
                trainable=True,
            )
            self.b = self.add_weight(
                shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
            )

        def call(self, inputs):
            return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b


    x = tf.ones((2, 2))

    # At instantiation, we don't know on what inputs this is going to get called
    linear_layer = Linear(32)

    # The layer's weights are created dynamically the first time the layer is called
    y = linear_layer(x)

    print(type(y))
    print(y)
```

Output is:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
Tensor("linear_17/add:0", shape=(2, 32), dtype=float32)
```

I need to get values of Tensor y. How to get them? tf.Session not working because I use Tensorflow 2.2.0.

Comment: would you like to extract the weights?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani with weights not problem, it is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and I could get weights values. Problem with output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear is a layer, you have to put it in a model structure

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b


x = tf.ones((2, 2))

inp = Input(2)
linear_layer = Linear(32)(inp)

model = Model(inp, linear_layer)
y = model.predict(x)
```

Comment: I get error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (inp = Input(2) row)

Comment: On my machine works, report the significative pice of the error please

Comment: in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    170                                    'dimension.')
    171     if shape is not None and not batch_shape:
--> 172         batch_shape = (None,) + tuple(shape)
    173     if not dtype:
    174         dtype = K.floatx()

Comment: I tryed "inp = Input(shape=(2,2))" but get another error: ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data).

Comment: No:( Same error in predict: ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data).

Comment: I know.. 2 is the feature dims... and I confirm that on my machine works (TF 2.2)

Comment: I have TF 2.2 too. What is your Keras version?

Comment: I use tf.keras instead of keras

Comment: Hmm, with tf.keras it works.. Very frustrated api. Probably I need refactor all my code. Tensorflow and Keras have poor documentation for this case (custom layers).

Comment: ahaha great... the mysteries of life